# How to extract particular links from html source code with regex

Tags: html, regex, hyperlink, notepad++, extract

I have html page with full of link. but they inside the pre tag like below

```
<pre class="alt2" dir="ltr" style="
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 6px;
        border: 1px inset;
        width: 640px;
        height: 130px;
        text-align: left;
        overflow: auto">
http://test.com/files/tivist.r00 
http://test.com/files/tivist.r01 
http://test.com/files/fdfd.rar 
http://test.com/files/gfgf.rar.html 
http://test.com/files/trtr.zip 
</pre>
</div><br />
```

The page is full of links like those

Is there any way get only those links form whole page.

I am using notepad++ . If i can get regex which can just extract those links

Comment: So you just want to remove whatever's not a link from your file?

Comment: yes , i want nice list of link starting from http and ending with whatever extension it has from above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following regex to find them all in the document.

```
http://[^\s]*
```

I guess you could edit it to or something similiar

```
http://[^\s"><]*
```

Comment: This is working but it is leaving the last link which ends with `...ist.rar</pre>`

Answer (score 1):

Besure you set the line by line option off.  Notepad++ has a very limited and poorly documented regex engine.  Try downloading editpad pro trial edition.

`(?<=\<pre.+?)http:\/\/.+?($|\s)(?=.+?\<\/pre\>)`

This should only get links that are within a `pre` tag.

### Here is a screen shot from Edit Pad Pro Trial edition

[image]

Comment: Sorry, notepad++ regex engine is terrible. this is good regex just try edit pad pro trial edition.  You'll like it's interface more anyways.  I did.

Comment: I installed that but the problem is that last <pre> tag is joined with .rar like  `.rar</pre>` so ur regex is not working. But if i put space between them , then it works. Can i do it without space

Comment: +1 On the EditPad recommend. But you no longer need the Pro version. [EditPadLite](http://www.editpadlite.com/) now includes regex search/replace!

Comment: @user1094163 I really have a hard time believing that my regex wouldn't work.  Since I included a screenshot of the results of the expression using your example code as the search text.